# Can I have a Vue app that has some static server rendered routes and some dynamic routes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

To improve SEO for my web app, I want the homepage to be server rendered by something like nuxt, but after logging in, I want a regular dynamic Vue app.

Comment: netlify offers some beta "Pre rendering" out of the box. Check https://www.netlify.com/docs/prerendering/, this may cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In nuxt you could do this with serverMiddleware.

```
export default function(req, res, next) {
  const paths = ['/', '/a']

  if (paths.includes(req.originalUrl)) {
    // Will trigger the "traditional SPA mode"
    res.spa = true
  }
  // Don't forget to call next in all cases!
  // Otherwise, your app will be stuck forever :|
  next()
}
```

https://blog.lichter.io/posts/selectively-enable-ssr-or-spa-mode-in-a-nuxtjs-ap